# How can I add Tab to an External Object's Search Layouts?

Tags: search-layout, externalobjects

I have two External Objects.  One I added a few weeks ago and it has a Tab Search Layout:

[image]

I can't remember how I gave it a Tab Search Layout but I need that for the following External Object (which is missing Tab):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a tab for External Objects in the same way that you do for custom objects. Search for "Tabs" in the Setup quick find box, and create a new Custom Object Tab. The external object will be shown in the list along with the other custom objects in the org.